# Data not pasting into Userform Textbox from Device input

Tags: excel, vba, serial-port, userform, serial-communication

I am trying to get data from a device to be input into a series of textboxes in a userform to be entered into a database.  The communication from the device will paste into a raw excel file perfectly fine.  But doesn't paste a single measurement into the userform textboxes.  I can hit "CTRL + V" afterwards and the last measurement will be input into the textbox.  Is there some control or communication protocol that I need in order for the data to be auto-input into the boxes?

[image: userform with pasted last value]

communication from the device is via usb and setting on it are as seen here

[image: RS232 config menu]

Comment: Is your userform modeless, and what code are you using to input the value, currently?

Comment: I don't understand "Modeless".  and the gaging software has a setting to "send to..."  and then you choose can choose your sequencing and the RS232 config as seen above